# Get coordinates after editing google map

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am storing the coordinates of a polygon marked on googlemap into mysql database. And I can plot that polygon in the edit page. My Problem is, when I edit the map by dragging the points, how I can get the new coordinates. I read google map docs, User-Editable Shapes but I cant get it. Please help me.

Thanks in advance
iijb

Comment: how do users edit the polygon? dragging markers? then marker.getPosition() is your friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the documentation for [Polygon.getPaths](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polygon)

[Here is an example map](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-draggable2Xml.html) that gets the path (not paths because polylines don't have that method) and uses the results to create xml in a text box.

Comment: Can you give some more details

Comment: What is your question?  Edited my answer to include an example.

Comment: If I change the polyline in the edit page, how to get new coordinates.

Comment: If you call the getPaths method on the polygon, it will return an MVCArray containing the coordinates, iterate through it and retrieve the coordinates as in the example (with the caveat that if your polygon has multiple paths, you will need to change the code to get the additional MVCArrays and extract their coordinates also).

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
var map;
    var coords = [];
    var lats = [];
    var lngs = [];
    var myMarkers = [];
    var myPoly;
    function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(17.397821, 78.479354);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
        addEventListener_marker();

    }
    function addEventListener_marker() {
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (e) {
            coords.push(e.latLng);
            lats.push(e.latLng.lb);
            lngs.push(e.latLng.mb);
            placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
        });
    }

    function placeMarker(position, map) {
        var mark = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            draggable: false
        });
        myMarkers.push(mark);
    }

    function createPoly() {
        polyOptions = {
            path: coords,
            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: "#FF6803",
            fillOpacity: '0.25',
            draggable: true,
            editable: true
        }
        myPoly = new google.maps.Polygon(polyOptions);
        myPoly.setMap(map);
        google.maps.event.addListener(myPoly, 'click', isWithinPoly);
        markerCoords();
        //removeEventListener();
        clearOverlays();

    }

    function markerCoords() {
        var curLatLng = [];
        curLatLng = myPoly.getPath().getArray();
        $("#info").append("coordinates are: Latitude: " + curLatLng + "<br/>");
        //google.maps.event.addListener(myPoly, 'shape_changed', function () {
        google.maps.event.addListener(myPoly, 'dragend', function () {
            //alert("drag end");
            var curLatLng;
            curLatLng = myPoly.getPath().getArray();
            $("#info").append("coordinates are: Latitude: " + curLatLng + "<br/>");
        });





    }

    function removeEventListener() {
        //google.maps.event.clearListeners(map, 'bounds_changed');
    }
    function clearOverlays() {
        setAllMap(null);
    }
    function setAllMap(map) {
        for (var i = 0; i < myMarkers.length; i++) {
            myMarkers[i].setMap(map);
        }
    }
    function isWithinPoly(event) {
        var isWithinPolygon = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(event.latLng, this);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```